# Genomic DNA isolation from wheat

Tags: molecular-biology, botany, molecular-genetics, methods

Can I use dry seed, wheat for example, in place of young leaves for isolation and purification of genomic DNA for PCR amplification?

The goal of my experiment is to validate a novel gene which is either absent or present at a particular chromosome.

Comment: That depends a lot on what you want to do in later analysis, especially if you need high molecular weight DNA or not. Please include all relevant details in you question, especially what you already found in your own research. One paper that is very easily found by google would be this one: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3131572/

Comment: I want to validate a novel gene which is absent or present at particular chromosome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes sure I tried this and give good result. But you most chose the best protocol and need to be do this manually. I recommend that use CTAB-PVP (which is use 3 buffers EBA EBB SDS %10) extraction method from "Integrated DNA technologies" and if you cant find this I will tell You.